Batch update with Multiple values in Single column of Sharepoint List from VBA
Is there any method to execute a batch update with multiple values for single column of Sharepoint list by VBA?
In the case of applying a batch update with single value for single column to multiple rows, I've got that the following code is suitable to do this with good performance.
My past post
Sub SPListUpdate_single_value_multiple_rows()
    
    Const ServerUrl As String = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/"
    Const ListName As String = "{e5r6t7h8-3d0e-4890-8111-3531bde50f4k}" 'List GUID
    
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim Sql As String
    Dim Batch_size as Integer
    Dim Target_rows as String
    
    With Conn ' Open the connection
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
                             "DATABASE=" & ServerUrl & ";" & _
                             "LIST=" & ListName & ";"
        .Open
    End With
    
    Target_rows = ""
    Batch_size = 50
    For i = 1 to 999
        If (i Mod Batch_size) = 0 OR i = 999 Then
            Target_rows = Target_rows & i
            Sql = "update [" & ListName & "] set [Col] = 'A' where [Title] in (" & Target_rows & ")"
            Conn.Execute Sql
            Target_rows = ""
        Else
            Target_rows = Target_rows & i & ","
        End if
    Next
    
End Sub

I wonder if there is a SQL command for VBA that can execute the update to the right side table in the following image at one time.

I tried the following SQL (MySQL?) commands but those are not available for VBA (Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library).
INSERT INTO ListName (Title, Col) 
VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'),... 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Col = VALUES(Col)

UPDATE ListName 
SET Col = ELT(FIELD(Title, 1, 2, 3,...), 'A', 'B', 'C',...) 
WHERE Title IN (1, 2, 3, ...)

